# Alternative to eval for converting a string to an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval

I have a function that is using eval to convert a string with an expression to an object based on the parameter.

```
let indexType = ["Mac", "User", "Line", "Mask", "Ip", "Location"]

const filterIndex = (item) => {
  filteredIndexSearch = []
  eval(`search${item}`).forEach((e) => filteredIndexSearch.push(searchData[e.key]))
}

filterIndex(indexType[searchTotal.indexOf(Math.max(...searchTotal))])
```

searchData is an array that returns values based on the user input.

searchTotal is an array with the length of each search{item} array.

The filterIndex function takes the highest value from the searchData array and corresponds it to the indexType array, then use eval to convert the string to an object to pass the value to the filteredIndexSearch array.

What would be a better alternative to eval?

**EDIT**

To add more information on what this does:

```
searchData = [
  [
    {
      key: 1,
      data: "0123456789101"
    },
    {
      key: 1,
      data: "John Smith"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      key: 2,
      data: "0123456789102"
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      data: "Jane Smith"
    },
  ]
]

const search = (data, key, container) => {
  if (!data) data = "";
  if (data.toLowerCase().includes(string)) {
    container = container[container.length] = {
      key: key,
      data: data
    }
  }
}

const returnSearch = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < searchData.length; i++) {
    search(searchData[i][0].data, searchData[i][0].key, searchMac)
    search(searchData[i][1].data, searchData[i][1].key, searchUser)
  }
}

returnSearch()
```

The data is incomplete, but hopefully conveys what I'm trying to do.

search will take the user input, and store the information in the corresponding array. If I input "Jo", it will return the searchUser array with only the "John Smith" value and all the other values with the same key. Inputting "102" returns the searchMac with the "0123456789102" value and all other values with the same key.

At the end of the day. I just want to convert `search${parameter}` to an object without using `eval`.

Comment: Stop using `searh0`, `search1` etc, and put them all in one array/object.

Comment: what it the code doing? do you have an example with data and wanted result?

Comment: So you are reinventing an object with multiple variables?
`var search = {
Mac: [....], User: [....]
};

var data = search[item];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your global arrays into an object.

Somewhere it appears that you're defining the arrays, something like:

```js
searchMac = [...];
searchUser = [...];
...
```

Instead of defining them as individual arrays, I'd define them as properties in an object:

```js
searchIndices.Mac = [...];
searchIndices.User = [...];
...
```

Then, instead of using `eval`, your can replace your `eval().forEach` with `searchIndices[item].forEach`.

If the order of your search isn't important, your can instead loop through the keys of `searchIndices`:

```js
Object.keys(searchIndices).forEach(item => {
  searchIndices[item].forEach(...);
});
```

This ensures that if you ever add or drop an entry in `searchIndices`, you won't miss it or accidentally error out on an undefined search index.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have a situation with variables named x0, x1 etc, that should be a red flag to tell you you should be using an array instead. Variable names should never be semantically meaningful - that is code should *never* rely on the name of a variable to determine how the code behaves. Convert `search0` etc into an array of `search` terms. Then use:

```
 const filterIndex = (item) => search[item].map(i => searchData[i.key]);
 filteredIndexSearch = filterIndex(indexType[searchTotal.indexOf(Math.max(...searchTotal))]);
```

(simplifying your code). Note that in your code, filteredIndexSearch is modified inside the arrow function. Better to have it return the result as above.

Comment: Adding it to an array is better, but only changes it to eval(`search${search.item}`).
My code is returning the most relevant search based on input. if the input most resembles the mac address, it will return the `searchMac` value by `eval`.

I'm probably not grasping the recommendations here, and will try converting the `search...` to an array and come back later.

Comment: If the `item` is a string rather than a number, then you can still use this code, but rather than `search` being an array, it would be an object with keys 'Mac', 'User" etc. and array values (per epascarello's comment).